# Do Experience modifiers affect the amount of experience shared by the Exp. Share?

Tags: pokemon-series

Experience modifiers include the Lucky Egg, Affection, and being traded. Do Pokémon that  did not participate gain 50% of the boosted Exp. or the base Exp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, those bonuses are applied after the sharing.

The total experience gained is calculated depending on the species of the Pokemon defeated (or catched) and its level, and the type of battle (wild or trainer), then this amount is divided by half and given to the Pokemon holding the Exp. Share<sup>Gen II-V</sup> or to all of the party<sup>Gen VI+</sup>. Then, that value is affected by various factors listed below.

This means that the Pokemon you are training gains more experience if it's traded or is helding a Lucky Egg. The origin or the held item of who actually defeats the enemy Pokemon don't affect the shared experience.

> This is the Experience Formula:
>
> [image]
>
> **a** is equal to:
>
> - 1 if the fainted Pokémon is wild
> - 1.5 if the fainted Pokémon is owned by a Trainer
>
> **b** is the base experience yield of the fainted Pokémon's species;
> values for the current Generation are listed [here](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/List_of_Pok%C3%A9mon_by_effort_value_yield)
>
> **e** is equal to:
>
> - 1.5 if the Pokémon is holding a Lucky Egg
> - 1 otherwise
>
> **f** is equal to:
>
> - 1.2 if the Pokémon has an Affection of two hearts or more
> - 1 otherwise
>
> **L** is the level of the fainted Pokémon
>
> **p** is equal to:
>
> - 1 if no Exp. Point O-Power is active
> - 1.2 for ↑, 1.5 for ↑↑, or 2 for ↑↑↑, if Exp. Point O-Power is active
>
> **s** is equal to:
>
> - 1 when calculating the experience of a Pokémon that participated in battle
> - 2 when calculating the experience of a Pokémon that did not participate in battle and if Exp. Share is turned on
>
> **t** is equal to:
>
> - 1 if the Pokémon's current owner is its Original Trainer
> - 1.5 if the Pokémon was gained in a domestic trade
> - 1.7 if the Pokémon was gained in an international trade
>
> **v** is equal to:
>
> - 1.2 if the Pokémon is at or past the level where it would be able to evolve, but it has not
> - 1 otherwise

Note that **a**, **b** and **L** are overall variables (affected by the battle and the enemy), they are the same for each of your Pokemon, that's why they are applied before the sharing.

These are all current values for Gen VI. Further information [here](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Experience#Gain_formula).

Comment: Ah, okay. Always thought experience was increased before the sharing. Thanks! :D